# Function not being executed at all or doesn't execute properly

Tags: c, embedded, firmware, 8051, sdcc

i'm working on an embedded C program, where the killnoise function is not executed even if it is called and the program always reach it, but when i chek the values at the output of this function i just discover that nothig happened:

```
void KillNoise( int* array, int size )
{
  int k;

    for (k=0;k<size;k++)
    {
       if (array[k] < 20)
           array[k] = 0;
    }

}
```

here is where and how i call it :

```
void UX_zswDecide( void )
{
    float __xdata centerOfMass[UX_NUM_SENSORS];
    float __xdata vectx, vecty, module, tg;
    int __xdata i,j;

    KillNoise( UX_bigUpArray,    NUMPOINTS );
    KillNoise( UX_bigDownArray,  NUMPOINTS );
    KillNoise( UX_bigLeftArray, NUMPOINTS );
    KillNoise( UX_bigRightArray,  NUMPOINTS );

/* the rest of the function */ 
}
```

where NUMPOINTS, biguparray, bigleftarray ... are global variables declared previously:

```
int   __xdata UX_bigUpArray[100];

int   __xdata UX_bigDownArray[100] ;

int   __xdata UX_bigLeftArray[100];
int   __xdata UX_bigRightArray[100] ;

#define NUMPOINTS 100
```

thank you a lot for your help, (i'm facing the same issue with another function)

Comment: This looks ok in isolation.  Can you provide a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Based on the data you provided, your code seems to be OK. There is something else we don't see that cause your code not working.

Comment: Nothing would happen if all the values in the array were equal to or greater than 20.

Comment: are you sure that UX_zswDecide(()is executing? if it was not executing then KillNoise() will not be called

Comment: i'm sure the UX_zswDecide() is executed the debuger even shows that the program enters to killnoise() but the output is the same as the input the big**arrays stay unchanged even if there is a lot of values less than 20

Comment: what's important of __xdata here?

Comment: just for testing mask all member of that array to 0 and cross check that that function is realy calling...!! we dont have full PICTURE so we cant help you more..

Comment: I believe that `__xdata` sticks the variable into external RAM rather than processor memory.

Comment: if i try to compile without __xdata i don't get enough memory space so the linking fails.

Comment: Is this a cut'n'paste from your source? If not, check you don't have a semi-colon after your for-loop!

Comment: @Nick ahh brilliant you are my savior from being expelled from job, hhhhhh

Comment: You're welcome! We've all done it before!

Comment: Had to upvote Nick's comment. Took me 5 mintues to figure it out. I thought he was referring to something in the pasted code, then I realized he just pulled that out of his head that the op had an extra semicolon in his code. I was off in the weeds wondering if the data were stored in ram or not.

Comment: actually, did someone believed Nick's comment ! For me it was a jock, hhhhh, I would hoped if it was as simple as that but unfortunately the problem stills unsolved,

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `__xdata` in the declaration of the `array` parameter in `KillNoise`

```
void KillNoise( int* __xdata array, int size )
```

or something similar.

Comment: yes if i compile without __xdata i get a linking error ( there isn't enought memory space)

Comment: @TarikMokafih:  But your example code just says `void KillNoise( int* array, int size )` I think you need `void KillNoise( int* __xdata array, int size )` or similar

Comment: i just tried it, no difference at all, could it be a debugger problem may be everything is ok, only the debugger doesn't refresh its values and shows every time the values before the killnoise function even if it is supposed to refresh it's values after every stop, there is also something weird i noticed when I’m running the program step by step, it seems that when it arrives to the end of the FOR loop the step by step debugger cursor just disappears while it's supposed to return to the beginning of the FOR loop

Comment: You don't *need* it but the code will be smaller and faster.